# OAuth2 flows for SPA with REST api

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I'm building a single-page application that will interact with an Authorization Server (in my case GitLab) and two Resource Servers (GitLab and my own REST api). My own REST api will also interact with GitLab on behalf of the user.

Now my question is whether to:

- use the implicit grant, which will result in the user having an `access_token` that can then be forwarded to our REST api so that both the SPA and the REST server can make requests to the resource provider on behalf of the user
- use the authorisation code grant where our REST api will exchange the code for an `access_token` and return it to the user
- use both (authorisation code grant for the REST server, implicit for the SPA)